# Verifying a signature with an explicitly given public key

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg

Suppose you want to distribute a file `foo` along with its detached signature `foo.sig` and your public key `public.key`.

Suppose further you want to make signature verification as easy as possible, i.e. in the minimum number of steps: just one command. Ideally something like

```
gpg2 [magic option combo here involving foo, foo.sig, public.key]
```

I've read the gpg2 man page up and down a few times, but it seems the receiver needs to first *import* the public key to his key ring.

Is there a way to avoid importing the public key and specify it explicitly? I would like to avoid the receiver being spammed with a newly created `$HOME/.gnupg` directory and its contents.

Or am I trying something stupid from a security point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gpgv` instead, which you can pass a keyring file (a single exported key also accounts as a keyring). If no slash is contained in the keyring path, `gpgv` will search in the GnuPG home directory, so either pass an absolute path or at least include `./` to denote the current working directory if no slash would be involved otherwise:

```
# Create and sign file
echo foo >foo.txt
gpg --local-user a4ff2279 --sign foo.txt
# Create "keyring" / export key
gpg --export a4ff2279 >a4ff2279.gpg
# Verify using gpgv
gpgv --keyring ./a4ff2279.gpg foo.txt.gpg
```

Finally, the only difference between importing and not importing the key is whether how the key is verified. There is no verification through the web of trust, certifications and local trust if you don't import the key, if the only way to verify the key is "downloading it from a trusted source", not importing it is totally fine. If you just fetch file, signature *and key* from an untrusted web server without encrypted connection and certificate, the OpenPGP signature is degraded to a simple checksum to realize transmission errors, not attacks providing faked files, signatures and keys.

Comment: Sweet. Also works with plain `gpg2 --keyring ./public.key --verify foo.sig foo`.

Comment: This will yield a message that the key could not be verified, which might be both acceptable or even appreciated.